# Android - Missing files between file explorers

Tags: android

I'm trying to access the two files, Spring v2.json and Test.json, in my Android app. However, I will add them using Windows with my phone connected, but when I run my app, the file seems to disappear.

**Getting the file**

```
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "Spring v2.json");
```

**Check is the file exists**

```
  if (file.exists()) {
    TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.download(
        "easelbucket",    // bucket to download from
        "sections/" + objectKey,        // key for object to be downloaded
        file          // file to download object to
    );
  } else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "File does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return null;
  }
```

I know that the file stops existing because (1) the if statement enters the else block, and (2) the app crashes when it attempts to use the result of the file.

[image: Windows File Explorer][image: Android File Explorer]

Comment: try to remove the blank space from the file name

Comment: It's a string literal, so it shouldn't make a difference. When I replace "Spring v2.json" with "Test.json", which is another file I have, the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "/Spring v2.json")
```

You forget slash before filename.
Also check if

```
.canRead();
```

and

```
.canExecute();
```

Comment: When I debug, the / is already there, so it is a correct file path. I don't believe my issue is the path, but the file just disappears in the Android Explorer.

Comment: I can already guess that those will return false, as the file ceases to exist once I try to run.

Comment: Files couldn't delete themselves. Maybe you've got some antivirus installed or something like that delete file on execution. Also you can try to set read-only permission on that file to check if your code runs normally.